# React-native-deck-swiper unable to install

Tags: react-native

So I try to install react-native-swiper but it gives me this error

```
While resolving: mybook@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0.0-beta.5" from react-native-deck-swiper@2.0.5  
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-deck-swiper
npm ERR!   react-native-deck-swiper@"^2.0.5" from the root project
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "mybook",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.5.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^9.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.7",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-deck-swiper": "^2.0.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

How can I keep using react-native-deck-swiper and still get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this earlier today and ended up using `npm install react-native-deck-swiper`. So far everything seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

npm install react-native-deck-swiper --force

I am not sure if it is right to force the installation, but I update my react and I run the code after to download my swiper package