# React Native deck swiper library not working

Tags: react-native, npm

I am trying to install the react native deck swiper using npm and I am getting the following error. Guys is the something wrong with this library "npm install react-native-deck-swiper" and if there is how do we fix it?

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-deck-swiper@2.0.8
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.69.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/cli@"^8.0.4" from react-native@0.69.5
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-navigation/elements@1.3.5
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/elements
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/elements@"^1.3.5" from @react-navigation/native-stack@6.8.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@react-navigation/native-stack
npm ERR!       @react-navigation/native-stack@"^6.8.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   6 more (@react-navigation/native, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"^0.49.1" from react-native-deck-swiper@2.0.8
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-deck-swiper
npm ERR!   react-native-deck-swiper@"^2.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native@0.49.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"^0.49.1" from react-native-deck-swiper@2.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-deck-swiper
npm ERR!     react-native-deck-swiper@"^2.0.8" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Leago\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Leago\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-31T23_17_27_722Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you, I found out it's more related to the command npm, apparently it works with yarn.
You can check these two links in which the problem is treated, but  I don't think forcing the installation with **npm install --force** is a good idea:

- [React-native-deck-swiper unable to install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71274076/react-native-deck-swiper-unable-to-install)
- https://github.com/alexbrillant/react-native-deck-swiper/issues/337